# Click event on li elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Right now I have my navigation like this:

```
<div>
    <div id="navbar">
        <a class="nav" id="Cars" >Cars</a>
        <a class="nav Active Home" >Home</a>
        <a class="nav" id="Brands" >Brands</a>  
    </div>
</div>
```

And I execute jquery code with a click event, like this:

```
$(".Home").click(function() {
    cont.executeCarsPanorama();
    $("#Cars").removeClass("Active");
    $("#Brands").removeClass("Active");
    $(".Home").addClass("Active");
})
```

**Now how would I execute the jQuery code if I want to use `<li>` rather than `<a>` tags?**

A click event can't be triggered on a `li` I think?

Comment: Yes you can add a click event on li tags

Comment: Any element can respond to a click. Now, that said, it's a good idea to always use appropriate elements for interaction. You could for example put your `<a>` elements *inside* the `<li>` elements.

Comment: You have no `li` elements

Comment: I'm tired of people asking without testing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove any active classes from any li element, but it then adds Active class to the one that you clicked.

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $('li').removeClass('Active');
    $(this).addClass('Active');
});
```

Comment: +1 for showing what OP needs, but this is shorter `$(this).addClass('Active').siblings().removeClass('Active');`

Answer (score 4):

```
$("li").click(function(){
    //your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
$('#navbar li').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('Active')
    $(this).addClass('Active');
    // Do other stuff
});
```

If you are going to put a click event on an `<li>` (which you can), you should restrict to #navbar else you can get unintended effects if people click around the page and on other `<li>`.